# What is the correct config of logstash input and output?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to know if my configuration is correct.

My configuration (in the file logstash_conf/first-pipeline.conf) is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash_conf/logstash-tutorial-dataset.log"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
  }

  geoip {
    source => "clientip"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {}

  stdout {}
}
```

I refered to the following configuration:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

But when I try to run logstash, the following error appears:

```
[root@laoyang bin]# ./logstash -f ./logstash_conf/first-pipeline.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 16
Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
Pipeline main started
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Is your ES server running? What do you get when executing `curl -XGET locahost:9200` ? Does it work if you comment out the `elasticsearch{}` output?

Comment: The configuration does not have any syntax error, the problem comes from the connection to Elasticsearch, which is expected to be accessible at localhost:9200 by default (since you did not specify any hosts).

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` means Lostash can't connect to Elasticsearch.

To follow this [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html), you should make sure your Elasticsearch is running on the same machine with Logstash.

```
root@laoyang bin]# curl http://localhost:9200
```

The above command should return Elastichsearch response.

```
output {
elasticsearch {}
stdout {}
}
```

The above example assumes Logstash and Elasticsearch to be running on the same instance. You can specify a remote Elasticsearch instance (i.e 192.168.1.1) using hosts configuration like:

```
output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "192.168.1.1:9200" ]
}
stdout {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   Now I running ok, and my configration is as follows:  input {
file {
path=> "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash_conf/Debug.log"
type=>"ttlog"
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "*.*.*.*:9200"
index => "tt_index"
}
stdout { codec => json_lines }
}